# Unable to Access Host machine’s postgres service from ASP.NET core WEB APi application in docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have a unique problem. I’m create an ASP.NET core application that will be accessing a postgres SQL on a host machine or host network. For development purpose I have community edition of docker on Windows 10 machine. I also have the POSTGRESQL on the same windows machine. I have exposed the ASP.NET service on the port 5000. The docker is a Linux docker and not windows docker
I have build the docker using the below dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000"
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT [“dotnet”, “ContainerDASample.dll”]
```

when I run the docker normally using the command

**docker run -p 5000:5000 --name containerda containerda-img**

*The health check (which is nothing but a Http 200 with a message )is working good but the endpoints that access the postgres are failing*

When I run the docker command using the below command

**docker run -p 5000:5000 --network=“host” --name containerda containerda-img**

*The health check itself fails.*

So totally I’m at loss to understand how to make this application work with container

Adding more information as per comments

1) Yes when I set the --network=host the endpoint localhost:5000

2) I use docker on windows 10 with Hyper-V

The health check simply not reachable. I ran the docker command as below
docker run -p 5000:5000 --network=host --name containerda containda-img

Comment: Can you provide more details about the failing endpoints? Which endpoints (localhost:5000?) and which error (Timeout?).

Comment: Using docker toolbox or docker for windows? Also post more details about your healtcheck and other failures